# How to request a signature field for each recipient when creating an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

1. Visibility issue:
   I have setup the docusign API on my app.
   Everything is working but I can't find in the docusign documentation how to request at least a Signature field in the envelope for each recipient.
   Today the sender can send the envelope without adding any field the envelope... Here a screenshot with the ability to send an envelope on my PROD account without adding any field to my envelope.
   [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDTmE.jpg)
   But I do not have the visibility option you talked about inside my PROD account
   [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo2Aa.jpg)
2. Custom fields within the envelope
   I would like to disable the custom field creation during the envelope creation but I do not know how to achieve it.
   [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FupAi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Update: To prevent senders from sending envelopes without tags, update this under **Settings**:
[image]

Envelopes can be sent to recipients without [tabs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/) (or tags or fields) so that the recipient (signer) then has to drag-and-drop fields to the envelope. That is called "free-form" signing and appears to n**ot be what you want**.

To add tabs to the envelope you have to modify your API calls to include these elements. They relate to recipients so are nested under them in the JSON like this:

```
"recipients": {
         "signers": [
            {
                "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
                "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

The above uses [anchor strings](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/), but you can also position then using fixed position with `xPosition, yPosition, pageNumber and documentId`.

You can find the [full code example in 8 languages in the DocuSign Developer Center.](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/)

As for custom fields, go to the Settings (DocuSign Admin) and find:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I do not want to place a tab for a signer. I want the sender to be required to place at least one signature tab (field) for each recipient where he wants.

Comment: you can disable freeform signing in the "Settings" for the account.

Comment: You need to enable "Document Visibility" in the settings, let me update the answer.

Comment: I have this option on my dev account but not on my prod account

Comment: Do you see the different behavior in your dev account (correct) and prod account (incorrect) ?

Comment: For now I can't send envelope with the prod account, when I will be able I let you know. I have also another question, how can I disable the custom field creation during the envelope preparation ?

Comment: Do you have custom fields set in the account? I'm not clear what you mean. Also, is this on your dev account or prod account?

Comment: I have edited my previous post.

Comment: I updated the document

Comment: There is no option to disable custom fields in the section you mention.

Comment: Did you try under "Sending Settings"? is it disabled over there?

Comment: "allow admins to share custom fields" is the only settings I have related to custom fields. Even if it is not selected, the sender is able to create/select custom fields during the adding enveloppe fields step